# Word wrap without breaking words

Tags: html, email, css, word-wrap

I've been working with sending out a HTML-formatted e-mail using a web server, and so far it's been good (content and all displays nicely), except for word wrapping. A single line of text (user input) can go on and on and produces a horizontal scrollbar on popular e-mail web clients.

So I went to do some research. I implemented `<div style="width: 100%; word-break: break-word;"><!-- Content here --></div>` and it worked perfectly fine, *with the exception that* it began cutting up my words. What I'd like to do is to make them go to the next line, while retaining the word wrap.

Other online sources say that the `<div>` tag does do automatic word wrapping, but in the web clients it doesn't work this way. I'm guessing this might be due to some of the behind-the-scenes CSS, but I didn't really go and investigate.

Does anybody have any solution/suggestion to my problem? I wouldn't like to do server-side formatting; firstly I think it's a pain in the ass, and secondly I think it'd look different across different web e-mail clients... thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this additional property:

```
white-space: pre-line;
word-wrap: break-word;
```

See this reference for explanation of possible values: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

Comment: Do you have a model online somewhere?

Comment: It's my code that set me off... I converted all whitespaces to `&nbsp;` and it eventually became one whole long string. Removing that and applying the `white-space: pre-line;` style worked wonders, thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

It’s indeed something behind the scenes that prevents normal wrapping. We would really need to see behind the scenes, or at least at the scenes, to analyze the situation, but in a simple case, adding this CSS (on the `div`) should help:

```
white-space: normal;
```

It’s the initial value, but presumably overridden by something. If this does not help, try

```
white-space: normal !important;
```

Avoid `word-break: break-word`, because it really breaks words, as the name suggests. It is meant for use with writing systems that allow breaks anywhere.

Comment: Actually I need it to be `white-space: pre-line;`, because I need to preserve the user's input. I never knew that there was a CSS property called `white-space`, because I was replacing all my whitespaces with `&nbsp;`s... Thanks!